# Envoy front-proxy for SpringBoot service returns connection termination (503)

Tags: spring-boot, envoyproxy

I am trying Envoy as a front-proxy to a simple API built using Java Spring Boot. But it returns HTTP status 503: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
Same configuration works when I replace my service with python service provided in examples.

I am probably missing some trivial configuration - to proxy a REST-JSON service.
My Java code is as simple as below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class Application {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws Exception{
Customer cust = new Customer(id, "...", "...", new ArrayList<Order>());
return cust;
}
}
```

If I replace the above Java service with one of the python services provided in the example, it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide your YAML config and link to the example you mention?

Comment: hi @AmithSewnarain, many thanks for your response. it was some issues with networking setup; now I am able to make it work. Btw, are there any good working sample of envoy with grpc services? I could not find any. Thanks again.

Comment: @sdas could you add what the solution was that worked for you?

Comment: hi @green , my envoy container and service container were in different network. once I realized and brought them to a common one, it worked. Then on k8s internal DNS, there were no issues. But now I am struggling with gRPC :(

Comment: @sdas I am facing the same issue. Could you please tell me how you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of envoy-proxy are you using? It seems this was an issue with version 1.9 and was resolved with version 1.10

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/2871